# Facebook open Graph: Can the canonical URL point to a totally different domain?

Tags: facebook, facebook-like

Will facebook allow you to reference a unrelated domain in the open graph meta tags?

For instance lets say the user, Bill, navigated to the following page on my site:

```
http://BillsEmployer.MySite.Com/ProductSuggestions
```

within the  section in the html I have the following element

```
<meta property="og:url" 
      content="http://www.amazon.com/dp/1590593898/" />
```

Bear in mind, I'm only using Amazon as an example. My real implementation will not reference AMAZON. But it will reference a site that I don't actually have any control over.

If Facebook won't let me use a 3rd party site as a canonical URL, would I be able to reference a different domain that I do control? In other words could I point

http://CompanyA.MySite.com, http://CompanyB.MySite.Com, http://CompanyC.MySite.com all to a canonical URL at http://generic.MySite.com?